# Update to datastore not saved or reading from wrong ansestor?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

Trying to change the example here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore

But instead of a Greeting item I would like to save a Student item. Using AngularJS in static directories that interact with `/app` to get the data. I only have a POST and a GET where POST will save an entry and GET will display first 10 entries.

When I POST json it seems to be saved, the response is:

```
{"name": "name", "age": 22, "creator": "test@example.com"}
```

When I do the GET request to get the list however nothing is returned, I get: `[]`

Looking at my code and the sample code and going back and forth I can't find the difference. The sample code works and saves Greetings so something must be wrong with my code.

```
import logging
import cgi
import urllib
import json
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import webapp2

DEFAULT_DS_NAME = 'default_ds'

def student_key(ds_name=DEFAULT_DS_NAME):
    return ndb.Key('Student', ds_name)

class StudentModel(ndb.Model):
    creator = ndb.UserProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Student(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        st = json.loads(self.request.body)
        student = StudentModel(parent=student_key())
        if users.get_current_user():
            student.creator = users.get_current_user()
        student.name = st['name']
        student.age = st['age']
        key = student.put()
        logging.info(key.id())#logs a number
        st['creator']=student.creator.email()
        self.response.write(json.dumps(st));

    def get(self):
        student_query = StudentModel.query(
            ancestor=student_key()).order(-StudentModel.name)
        students = student_query.fetch(10)
        ret=[]
        for student in students:
            s={'name':'','age':0,'creator':''};
            if student.creator:
                s["creator"]=student.creator.email()
            s["name"]=student.name
            s["age"]=student.age
            logging.info("Pushing s");#never logs anything
            ret.push(s)
        self.response.write(json.dumps(ret))#returns []

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/app/student', Student)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to order query by unindexed field, so you need to set indexed=True to Student model:

```
name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```